# Where to define a local function in a AngularJS Directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Where do I have to define my function button() in the directive, such that pressing the button will trigger the function?

I don't want to use the outer scope of the app, I just want to use the local scope.

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.directive('aaaa', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      data: '=',
      //this is not working: button: function(){console.log('hello from button');}
    },
    link: function(scope, element) {
      element.append('hello');
      element.append(' <button type="button" ng-click="button()">Click Me!</button> ')
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">

  <aaaa></aaaa>

</div>
```

Comment: Well, your `ngClick` isn't going to do anything, ever. You cant just append an HTML string and expect it to be picked up - checkout using the `$compile` service to inject dynamic HTML

Comment: Agreeing with @tymeJV - - I think you are not using Angular directives correctly.  You'd be better off using a template than appending in the link function, and an associated controller for the ng-click.  The link is really for setting up any DOM manipulation or listeners that have no place in a controller.

Comment: @anied this i just an mwe, in my real scenario it makes sense to use the link function instead of template

Comment: Fair enough, then the selected answer is fine, I agree that leveraging `$compile` is the correct way to handle this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @tymeJV said , you need to compile the html first and then call button() in directive controller

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.directive('aaaa', function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      data: '=',
      //this is not working: button: function(){console.log('hello from button');}
    },
    link: function(scope, element) {
      element.append('hello');

     var htmlText = ' <button type="button" ng-click="button()">Click Me!</button> ';
      var template = angular.element($compile(htmlText)(scope));
      element.append(template);
    },
    controller: function($scope, $element){
       $scope.button = function(){
           console.log('button clicked');
       }
     }
  }
});
```

Comment: and where do i have to defne the function?

Comment: Oh, i just notice you dont have controller. You can define controller in directive then. Let me update my answer

Answer (score 0):

I would advise to use angular templates instead of element.append, see example code below. Then you don't need all the compiler code 'n stuff.

You could also replace "template: 'hello

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.directive('aaaa', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      data: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, element) {
      scope.button = function(){
      console.log('hello from button');
      };
    },
    template: 'hello <button type="button" ng-click="button()">Click Me!</button>'
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">

  <aaaa></aaaa>

</div>
```

Comment: Why use a link function instead of a controller for defining the scope.button function?

Comment: I saw a lot of answers that were appending dom, which is not the angular way to do it: templates are. 
So wanted to show an example how to use templates without overwhelming the TS with a bunch of other best-practices :-)

I would totally suggest to use:
- The directive's controller's scope (this) instead of "scope" (and with this use controller function instead of link function)
- Or use Angular 1.5's components instead of directives, so it's easier to migrate to ng2 later on. For more about these subjects google for "directive controllerAs"/"angular 1.5 components"

Answer (score -1):

you can out under link

```
  link: function(scope, element) {
      element.append('hello');
      element.append(' <button type="button" ng-click="button()">Click Me!</button> ');
      scope.button=function(){
          //content goes here
      }
  }
```